# Adding multiple objects to a docx document via docx4j

Tags: java, openxml, edit, docx4j

I manage to add an ellipse to a docx document but fail to add more than one.

This is the code I use:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage();

String xmlAnchor = getXmlAnchor(607000, 288000, 1);
Object anchorXml = XmlUtils.unmarshalString(xmlAnchor);
Anchor anchor = (Anchor) ((JAXBElement)anchorXml).getValue();

String xmlAnchor2 = getXmlAnchor(1110000, 1000000, 2);
Object anchorXml2 = XmlUtils.unmarshalString(xmlAnchor2);
Anchor anchor2 = (Anchor) ((JAXBElement)anchorXml2).getValue();

ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();
P paragraph = factory.createP();
P paragraph2 = factory.createP();
R run = factory.createR();
R run2 = factory.createR();
Drawing drawing = factory.createDrawing();
Drawing drawing2 = factory.createDrawing();

paragraph.getContent().add(run);
run.getContent().add(drawing);
drawing.getAnchorOrInline().add(anchor);

paragraph2.getContent().add(run2);
run2.getContent().add(drawing2);
drawing2.getAnchorOrInline().add(anchor2);

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().add(0, paragraph);
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContent().add(0, paragraph2);

wordMLPackage.save(new File(outputFilePath));
```

This is the *getXmlAnchor* method:

```
private static String getXmlAnchor(int x, int y, int id) {
    String xmlAnchor = ""
            + "<wp:anchor xmlns:wp14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing\" xmlns:wps=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape\" xmlns:wp=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing\" distT=\"0\" distB=\"0\" distL=\"114300\" distR=\"114300\" simplePos=\"0\" relativeHeight=\"251659264\" behindDoc=\"0\" locked=\"0\" layoutInCell=\"1\" allowOverlap=\"1\">"
            + "     <wp:simplePos x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
            + "     <wp:positionH relativeFrom=\"page\">"
            + "         <wp:posOffset>" + x + "</wp:posOffset>"
            + "     </wp:positionH>"
            + "     <wp:positionV relativeFrom=\"page\">"
            + "         <wp:posOffset>" + y + "</wp:posOffset>"
            + "     </wp:positionV>"
            + "     <wp:extent cx=\"130629\" cy=\"130629\"/>"
            + "     <wp:effectExtent l=\"0\" t=\"0\" r=\"22225\" b=\"22225\"/>"
            + "     <wp:wrapNone/>"
            + "     <wp:docPr id=\"1\" name=\"" + id +" Elipse\"/>"
            + "     <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>"
            + "     <a:graphic xmlns:a=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main\">"
            + "         <a:graphicData uri=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape\">"
            + "             <wps:wsp>"
            + "                 <wps:cNvSpPr/>"
            + "                 <wps:spPr>"
            + "                     <a:xfrm>"
            + "                         <a:off x=\"0\" y=\"0\"/>"
            + "                         <a:ext cx=\"130629\" cy=\"130629\"/>"
            + "                     </a:xfrm>"
            + "                     <a:prstGeom prst=\"ellipse\">"
            + "                         <a:avLst/>"
            + "                     </a:prstGeom>"
            + "                 </wps:spPr>"
            + "                 <wps:style>"
            + "                     <a:lnRef idx=\"2\">"
            + "                         <a:schemeClr val=\"accent1\">"
            + "                             <a:shade val=\"50000\"/>"
            + "                         </a:schemeClr>"
            + "                     </a:lnRef>"
            + "                     <a:fillRef idx=\"1\">"
            + "                         <a:schemeClr val=\"accent1\"/>"
            + "                     </a:fillRef>"
            + "                     <a:effectRef idx=\"0\">"
            + "                         <a:schemeClr val=\"accent1\"/>"
            + "                     </a:effectRef>"
            + "                     <a:fontRef idx=\"minor\">"
            + "                         <a:schemeClr val=\"lt1\"/>"
            + "                     </a:fontRef>"
            + "                 </wps:style>"
            + "                 <wps:bodyPr rot=\"0\" spcFirstLastPara=\"0\" vertOverflow=\"overflow\" horzOverflow=\"overflow\" vert=\"horz\" wrap=\"square\" lIns=\"91440\" tIns=\"45720\" rIns=\"91440\" bIns=\"45720\" numCol=\"1\" spcCol=\"0\" rtlCol=\"0\" fromWordArt=\"0\" anchor=\"ctr\" anchorCtr=\"0\" forceAA=\"0\" compatLnSpc=\"1\">"
            + "                     <a:prstTxWarp prst=\"textNoShape\">"
            + "                         <a:avLst/>"
            + "                     </a:prstTxWarp>"
            + "                     <a:noAutofit/>"
            + "                 </wps:bodyPr>"
            + "             </wps:wsp>"
            + "         </a:graphicData>"
            + "     </a:graphic>"
            + "     <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom=\"margin\">"
            + "         <wp14:pctWidth>0</wp14:pctWidth>"
            + "     </wp14:sizeRelH>"
            + "     <wp14:sizeRelV relativeFrom=\"margin\">"
            + "         <wp14:pctHeight>0</wp14:pctHeight>"
            + "     </wp14:sizeRelV>"
            + "</wp:anchor>";

    return xmlAnchor;
}
```

But the docx file can't be opened with MS Office. I also tried adding the two runs to the same paragraph, and so on. None seems to work.

This is the document.xml inside the generated docx file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:ns9="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/schemaLibrary/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chartDrawing" xmlns:dgm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/diagram" xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture" xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2008/diagram" xmlns:ns17="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:ns21="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:powerpoint" xmlns:ns23="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps" xmlns:odx="http://opendope.org/xpaths" xmlns:odc="http://opendope.org/conditions" xmlns:odq="http://opendope.org/questions" xmlns:oda="http://opendope.org/answers" xmlns:odi="http://opendope.org/components" xmlns:odgm="http://opendope.org/SmartArt/DataHierarchy" xmlns:ns30="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:ns31="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/compatibility" xmlns:ns32="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/lockedCanvas" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w14:paraId="6ab5171" w14:textId="6ab5171">
            <w:pPr>
                <w15:collapsed w:val="false"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:drawing>
                    <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="false" relativeHeight="251659264" behindDoc="false" locked="false" layoutInCell="true" allowOverlap="true">
                        <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                        <wp:positionH relativeFrom="page">
                            <wp:posOffset>1110000</wp:posOffset>
                        </wp:positionH>
                        <wp:positionV relativeFrom="page">
                            <wp:posOffset>1000000</wp:posOffset>
                        </wp:positionV>
                        <wp:extent cx="130629" cy="130629"/>
                        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="22225" b="22225"/>
                        <wp:wrapNone/>
                        <wp:docPr id="1" name="2 Elipse"/>
                        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
                        <a:graphic>
                            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                                <wps:wsp xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing">
                                    <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                                    <wps:spPr>
                                        <a:xfrm>
                                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                                            <a:ext cx="130629" cy="130629"/>
                                        </a:xfrm>
                                        <a:prstGeom prst="ellipse">
                                            <a:avLst/>
                                        </a:prstGeom>
                                    </wps:spPr>
                                    <wps:style>
                                        <a:lnRef idx="2">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
                                                <a:shade val="50000"/>
                                            </a:schemeClr>
                                        </a:lnRef>
                                        <a:fillRef idx="1">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                                        </a:fillRef>
                                        <a:effectRef idx="0">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                                        </a:effectRef>
                                        <a:fontRef idx="minor">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="lt1"/>
                                        </a:fontRef>
                                    </wps:style>
                                    <wps:bodyPr anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="0" bIns="45720" compatLnSpc="1" forceAA="0" fromWordArt="0" horzOverflow="overflow" lIns="91440" numCol="1" rIns="91440" rot="0" rtlCol="0" spcCol="0" spcFirstLastPara="0" tIns="45720" vert="horz" vertOverflow="overflow" wrap="square">
                                        <a:prstTxWarp prst="textNoShape">
                                            <a:avLst/>
                                        </a:prstTxWarp>
                                        <a:noAutofit/>
                                    </wps:bodyPr>
                                </wps:wsp>
                            </a:graphicData>
                        </a:graphic>
                    </wp:anchor>
                </w:drawing>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p>
            <w:r>
                <w:drawing>
                    <wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="114300" distR="114300" simplePos="false" relativeHeight="251659264" behindDoc="false" locked="false" layoutInCell="true" allowOverlap="true">
                        <wp:simplePos x="0" y="0"/>
                        <wp:positionH relativeFrom="page">
                            <wp:posOffset>607000</wp:posOffset>
                        </wp:positionH>
                        <wp:positionV relativeFrom="page">
                            <wp:posOffset>288000</wp:posOffset>
                        </wp:positionV>
                        <wp:extent cx="130629" cy="130629"/>
                        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="22225" b="22225"/>
                        <wp:wrapNone/>
                        <wp:docPr id="1" name="1 Elipse"/>
                        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr/>
                        <a:graphic>
                            <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                                <wps:wsp xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing">
                                    <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                                    <wps:spPr>
                                        <a:xfrm>
                                            <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                                            <a:ext cx="130629" cy="130629"/>
                                        </a:xfrm>
                                        <a:prstGeom prst="ellipse">
                                            <a:avLst/>
                                        </a:prstGeom>
                                    </wps:spPr>
                                    <wps:style>
                                        <a:lnRef idx="2">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1">
                                                <a:shade val="50000"/>
                                            </a:schemeClr>
                                        </a:lnRef>
                                        <a:fillRef idx="1">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                                        </a:fillRef>
                                        <a:effectRef idx="0">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="accent1"/>
                                        </a:effectRef>
                                        <a:fontRef idx="minor">
                                            <a:schemeClr val="lt1"/>
                                        </a:fontRef>
                                    </wps:style>
                                    <wps:bodyPr anchor="ctr" anchorCtr="0" bIns="45720" compatLnSpc="1" forceAA="0" fromWordArt="0" horzOverflow="overflow" lIns="91440" numCol="1" rIns="91440" rot="0" rtlCol="0" spcCol="0" spcFirstLastPara="0" tIns="45720" vert="horz" vertOverflow="overflow" wrap="square">
                                        <a:prstTxWarp prst="textNoShape">
                                            <a:avLst/>
                                        </a:prstTxWarp>
                                        <a:noAutofit/>
                                    </wps:bodyPr>
                                </wps:wsp>
                            </a:graphicData>
                        </a:graphic>
                    </wp:anchor>
                </w:drawing>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr>
            <w:pgSz w:w="11907" w:h="16839" w:code="9"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

The *ImageAdd* example (https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/ImageAdd.java) adds three paragraphs with no apparent complication.
I tried *wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addObject(paragraph)* but didn't worked neither.

Which is the correct way to accomplish multiple elements insertion?

Comment: At a guess, try using unique values for wp:docPr/@id?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. I changed the name attribute but not the id one. My bad.  
Thank you very much.